# Inner product and norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to show that if $\|x+y\|=\|x\|$ then $2x+y$ and $y$ are orthogonal. I think I can use Pythagoras. Thank for any help.

Corrected

Answer (score 3):

Pass to the square

$$\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\langle y,y\rangle\iff \langle x,x\rangle+2\langle x,y\rangle=0\iff\langle x,x+2y\rangle=0$$
so $x$ and $x+2y$ are orthogonal.

**Remark** The desired result isn't correct: just take $x=0$.

Comment: sorry there should be y instead of x after equation sign